# Call function inside by calling the object of a javascript class. I want to print the array of priority queue by calling the class object

Tags: javascript

Here is my Sample Code

```
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
  
  isEmpty() {
    if (this.items.length === 0) return true;
    return false;
  }

  hasValue(element) {
    return this.items.some((item) => item[0] === element);
  }
  peek() {
    this.isEmpty() 
    return this.items[0];
  }
  poll() {
    this.isEmpty() 
    return this.items.splice(0, 1);
  }
  add(number, priority) {
    if (priority===undefined) return this.items.push({ element: number, priority: null });
    if(this.isEmpty() || this.items[this.items.length-1].priority<priority)
    return this.items.push({ element: number, priority: priority })
    for (let i = this.items.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (this.items[i].priority <= priority)
        return this.items.splice(i+1 , 0, { element: number, priority: priority });
    }
    return this.items.splice(0 , 0, { element: number, priority: priority });
  }
  printAll(){
      return this.items.map(item=>item.element)
  }
}
var priorityQueue= new PriorityQueue();
priorityQueue.add(10, 1);
console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue.printAll())) // [10]
priorityQueue.add(100, 0);
console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue.printAll())) // [100,10]
priorityQueue.add(200, 0);
console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue.printAll())) // [100,200,10]
```

**But what I want `priorityQueue` object calls `printAll()` function inside the class. Is it possible? Can we handle with proxies?**
**This is what I want below**

```
 var priorityQueue= new PriorityQueue();
    priorityQueue.add(10, 1);
    console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue)) // [10]
    priorityQueue.add(100, 0);
    console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue)) // [100,10]
    priorityQueue.add(200, 0);
    console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue)) // [100,200,10]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.from` uses [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), so you can just define that with a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
class PriorityQueue {
  // other functions
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const item of this.items) {
      yield item.element;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info buddy. @Aplet123 .It Worked

Answer (score 2):

No, a proxy won't help with anything here.

The [`Array.from` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) converts an *iterable* object to an array, so what you want to do is to implement the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) on your priority queue instances:

```
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
  …
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const item of this.items) {
      yield item.element;
    }
  }
  // Alternatively:
  // [Symbol.iterator]() {
  //   return this.items.map(item => item.element).values()
  // }
}
```